# Does xubuntu 15.10 comes with trim enabled by default?

Tags: xubuntu, 15.10, ssd

How do I check if trim is enabled on Xubuntu 15.10?

I have a Samsung SSD 840 EVO and is **EXT0BB6Q**, the latest driver for my SSD?